# Django Refresh database until end of transaction

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a long task, that is adding many records to a database table.
In the table, there is a field called "end". This field will be empty until the task is done. As soon as the task is done, I will write a value in the "end" field.

Can I have an HTML page, that is refreshing the page every 5 seconds with the items from the table until the field "end" has a value?

Does somebody have an example script for this?

Comment: How do yoou run your `long task` ? Do you `Celery` ?

Comment: Yes with Celery

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty specific Problem, i don't think there is a ready example for that.

But you could simply use JavaScript in you HTML Template:

```
{% if end_column_empty %}

 <script>    
   setTimeout(function(){
     window.location.reload(1);
   }, 5000);
 <script>

{% else %}
 Table is Complete.
{% endif %}
```

The above code assumes that you do the long SQL-Task with Celery or somehow asynchron. The Code above won't work if your SQL-Job needs 50 seconds to finish, because it will break up after 5 seconds.

If you don't want to use Celery, you could do the SQL-Job as is, while updating the Table with jQuery - for that you'd need REST API trough which you would access your table data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use websocket. Socket is listening and wait on datas. Django the use form **django-channels**